# Browser width not 100% on iPad and iPhone, the rest is ok

Tags: iphone, html, css, mobile, width

For testing purpose i setup this page : http://www.fondationmartinmatte.com/test.html
it's pretty fine in html desktop browser, but in mobile there is always a vertical grey bar from hell remaining. where it come from and what setting should i tell the html code to use for mobile. First there was that code : `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`that make the whole thing worst. i just delete it, and here is the grey bar. how to fix that, thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using these:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"/>
```

Also, you might want to get a more sophisticated CSS reset than what you currently have (margin: 0, padding: 0). There are some great ones here to make your life easier when it comes to browser compatibility:

http://www.cssreset.com/

Comment: Would you mind explaining these line, and what each do. But for sure your a wise person, copy-pasting it make it a lot better ! thanks

Comment: It's a late response, wasn't around much lately. Last1Here gave a good basic explanation. To expand on it, what the first line does is basically limits what the mobile device can do with the website.

width=device-width is self-explanatory, basically it sets the total width of the site content to match the width of the device viewing it. 

initial-scale=1.0 sets the initial device zoom level to 100%

user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0 forbids the device/user from changing the zoom level, so it's always stuck to 100%. This makes sense only if the site is responsive of course.

Comment: The two lines below are just like Last1Here said, what they do is define how the website looks if opened via bookmark icon on iPhone or iPad. Not really that relevant/required, but a nice touch to complete the functionality.

Comment: Disabling zoom with `user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0` is terrible UX. There might be a use case here and there, but unless there is some really specific reason other than "I can't figure out how to make my thing look like I want it to", don't do it. By preventing zoom, you are hampering accessibility for sight impaired users and pissing people off who might just want to zoom in to get a better look at something.

Answer (score 3):

This scales your website to the device

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

The two lines below are for when a user adds your website to the homepage of their iOS device.
First line is for when they click the icon added it will not open in safari, the second line defines the status bar (bar with battery indicator and time) colour when they open your website from their homepage.

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

More information here : http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html